# Does loading data into page done on server or client side?

Tags: javascript, html, server

This is dumb but still, hard to clearly read how it works online without consuming a full book.

When a user type an address for a page with a photo gallery, and he would like to get this gallery loaded with photos related to some query he want, for instance `page.com/dogs` , which of those happens :

1. server read dogs, get data for dogs from DB, and return the page loaded already with dogs photos links ( = one request, one respond)
2. user ask `page.com/dogs` , and get the page, then the code on page read `dogs`, go to server and ask dog photos links data to load into page, get it back and load it (2 requests, 2 responds)

1 sounds more elegant and fast but looks like sites still use 2.
Is it so ? how its done most of the time ?

Comment: Both options are quite viable

Comment: Why would anyone use 2 ? its more slowly, one more request, more server costs, no?

Comment: Server might want to attempt JS validation that the client is real and not a bot first, is one possible reason

Comment: ah great thanks, is there any other reason? how for instance Facebook works? how much more slowly approach 2 is ?

Comment: Number 2 is often faster when you'll be looking at more than one thing. For example after `/dogs` on the next request they ask for `/cats` or something else. All the html and css code is the same for the gallery, so the page need only request data on cats, which is small. The server sends as JSON, then the page replaces the images and links with the new cat data.

Comment: Facebook also loads the page incrementally, adding to the feed as you scroll. So at first it makes a request for one batch of data, then if it needs more it makes more requests. That can save a lot of traffic over loading a whole bunch at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you could implement this either way.

Option 1 is typically the best, because it would reduce the amount of network latency required to display the page to the user. Keep in mind that this option would still require more than one request for images, unless they are encoded into the HTML document (i.e. base64).

Option 2 would only be better if the main page is a large payload and the images change frequently and are requested via AJAX. YouTube and Google use a similar implementation. This allows users to cache the main (skeleton) page and therefore reduce bandwidth required.

You likely wouldn't see any benefit from using option 2 unless the application received a lot of traffic from the same users AND the skeleton page doesn't change often.